# php mysql trying to use empty to only add a new record in table if a primary key exists in a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, xampp

I am trying to only allow a submission via the form only if a party_id exists in a table using empty, here is  my code at the moment it is still allowing everything through even if there is no party_id. 
Any help would be great.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST") {
        $party_id = (int)$_POST["partyid"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $date = $_POST["date"];
        $length = (int)$_POST["length"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `party` WHERE `party_id`='" . $party_id . "'";  
        $res = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
        if(empty($party_id)) { #Were any records found?
            print '<p>No Parties with that ID found! please press the back button to select another party</p>'; 
        } else {
            $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $party_name =  $record["party_name"];
            $price = $record["price"];
            $cost = $price * $length;
            $bookable = true;
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `reservations`" or die("Unable to connect to database");
```

Comment: Are you aware your `$party_id` doesn't hold the `result` from the `SELECT` query it holds the value from `$_POST["partyid"]`

Comment: I am a bit of a newbie sorry, does $res hold the result?

Comment: I have tried using $res but it still lets everything through is it because I am querying all columns? That it doesn't see it as empty?

Comment: No `$res` hold a handle to the result set producted by `mysqli_query()` If all else fails [There is aways the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) As a totally last resort of course

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way might be to just check if the query returned any results like this.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST") {
        $party_id = (int)$_POST["partyid"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $date = $_POST["date"];
        $length = (int)$_POST["length"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `party` WHERE `party_id`='$party_id'";  
        $res = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 

        if ( mysqli_num_rows($res ) == 0 ) {
            print '<p>No Parties with that ID found! please press the back button to select another party</p>'; 
        } else {
            $record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $party_name =  $record["party_name"];
            $price = $record["price"];
            $cost = $price * $length;
            $bookable = true;
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `reservations`" or die("Unable to connect to database");
```

Comment: Thanks for this Riggs I keep getting these errors?
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in E:\xampp\htdocs\Party\reservations4.php on line 23
No Parties with that ID found! please press the back button to select another party      Won't let anything through whether it has an id or not?

Comment: Woops, little typo in my answer. I fixed it. It should have been `mysqli_num_rows($res )`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer helped its normal to Upvote it. If it answered your question its normal to accept the answer